# Powershell - SetMailboxFolderPermission only if AccessRights Not equal Reviewer

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory, calendar, exchange-server

I'd like to make a script to set the access rights for everyone as "Reviewer" on the calendar of some users, members of an specific AD group.

I've already made a script which works weel to do that for all members of this group.
I'd just want to make it a little smarter.

I'd like to schedule this script to run automatically once a week and to only apply on mailboxes on which accessrights are not already set as "Reviewer" for everyone.

Something like that :

```
$comm = Get-ADGroupMember GG_CalendarPermission-Reviewer | select -ExpandProperty name
$GetCalendar = Get-mailboxfolderpermission -identity $user":\calendar" -user default

foreach ($user in $comm) {    
  if ($GetCalendar.AccessRights -ne "Reviewer") {
       set-mailboxfolderpermission -identity $user":\calendar" -user Default -accessrights reviewer
  }
  elseif($GetCalendar.AccessRights -eq "Reviewer") {
       Write-Host "ALREADY DONE"
  }    
}
```

But the "if/Elseif" doesn't seems to work :/ 
Could you help me please ?

Thanks.

Comment: $GetCalendar code should be inside foreach statement

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help Vincent. It works with the $Get-Calendar inside the foreach statement :)

Do you know how could I add a {Write-Host "Done"} after the firts "if", when the command "Set-Mailboxfolderpermission" successfully apply please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$comm = Get-ADGroupMember GG_CalendarPermission-Reviewer | select -ExpandProperty name

foreach ($user in $comm) {
  $GetCalendar = Get-Mailboxfolderpermission -identity $user":\calendar" -user default

  If ($GetCalendar.AccessRights -ne "Reviewer") {
       Set-Mailboxfolderpermission -identity $user":\calendar" -user Default -accessrights reviewer
       Write-Host 'Done'
  }
  ElseIf($GetCalendar.AccessRights -eq "Reviewer") {
       Write-Host "ALREADY DONE"
  }    
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly now. Thanks a lot for you help again :)